# Navigation in iOS like this image

Tags: ios, user-interface

I like the navigation that can be seen here:

[image]

But I don't know how to do it. Could someone point me to a tutorial how to do it or could tell me some keywords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Add four buttons to your view..arrange them in 2x2 format.
- You should do it in Interface Builder..then just make an IBAction for
  each button..

Answer (score 1):

For creating odd shaped buttons use - https://github.com/ole/OBShapedButton

It's a fantastic button class that allows buttons that are not just rectangles.